# Mapping of URLs to Azure WebRoles

Tags: azure, url, azure-web-roles, endpoint

I cannot find any high level discussion docs that describe how URLs are mapped to Azure WebRoles in the case where an application has multiple WebRoles.

Is it:

```
roleA.myApp.com to WebRoleA
roleB.myApp.com to WebRoleB
```

or:

```
www.myApp.com/roleA to WebRoleA
www.myApp.com/roleB to WebRoleB
```

The answer to this question will help me decide what type of SSL certificate(s) my Azure application will need.

Note: I understand a WebRole can have a configured number of instances, but in this question I am discussing different WebRoles within an app.

Answer (score 0):

Each web role gets its own port as its endpoint differentiator. Typically you'd hit port 80 (or 443). You'll need to choose non-standard ports for the 2nd webrole.

Here's what the configuration form looks like in VS2010, when configuring a webrole. I simply added two web roles, and chose the 2nd one. I can now specify the port as well as the certificate, for the specific webrole.

[image: VS2010 RC webrole configuration]

Comment: Thanks David but I am still confused. If a web role equates to a separate VM and, as you say, gets its own IP address then I hope different WebRoles within an app can listen on a common port? Anyhow given what you say about distinct IP addresses then I assume the URL format must be WebRoleA.myApp.com and WebRoleB.myApp.com

Comment: Crap - not IP address - I meant port! And the web roles live in the same vm, unless you crank up the instance count. Sorry about that - I'll edit my response post-haste.

Comment: Where you say "the web roles live in the same vm", are you sure about that? At the Azure feature voting site the request for multiple WebRoles per VM is a popular request.

Comment: I just went and read up on the azure voting thread. Interesting - I was under the belief you could break things up by role, as I have been recently doing on a project. I was also at the PDC SVC01 session mentioned, where they alluded to multiple web roles per VM. I need to dig into this further, but it looks like I stand corrected on the multi-role-per-vm comment.